# differentiation between exception

Tags: java, exception

I've read that exceptions in Java are differentiated by being either checked and unchecked. How does a compiler know that an exception is a checked exception?

Also since all exceptions are extending extending the class `Exception` - is there any flag that is set to true for the compiler to mark the exception as a checked exception...

What is happening behind the scene?

I am just curious too to know about it..

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is a `RuntimeException` or a subclass is *unchecked*.

See the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) for more information or the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html)

Comment: What you had suggested, I have already read it but did not found any solid evidence where I could say that, this is major reason...what flag or what makes it happen, I barely don't know...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to the relevant part of the JLS, this should be your definitive evidence